# Facebook graph api and FQL mismatch

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Graph api and equivalent FQL method give different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225198/graph-api-and-equivalent-fql-method-give-different-results)

I'd like to query an event on facebook filtered by time and location.

According to the graph api, an event has a field called venue, which is an **object** that has latitude and longitude.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

However, according to the facebook query language, the event table has a field called venue, which is a **string**.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/

There doesn't seem to be a venue table of which the venue string could be a foreign key.

How could I get a list of venues near a coordinate with FQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the documentation; thanks for pointing it out! Documentation has been updated to reflect the fact that 'venue' actually contains the fields in the venue object that's returned by the Graph API.

You can search for locations using the Graph API's /search endpoint. For example, you can search for a place related to "coffee" with the following query [https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&access_token=...](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3Dcoffee%26type%3Dplace%26center%3D37.76%2C-122.427%26distance%3D1000) See the [Searching section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching) in the [Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for correcting it. I'd need to search for a **list of events around a coordinate during a period of time**. The FQL query I made returns that "_venue_ or _start_time_ is not indexed therefore cannot be used in a WHERE clause."