# Graph api and equivalent FQL method give different results?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

**1.** When I used this method, I get a list of events that I'm attending.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=...

You can try it yourself, scroll to the middle of the page and click the link

Source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

**2.** When I use this method, I get no results.

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+eid+from+event_member+WHERE+uid+%3D+me%28%29+&access_token=...&format=json

The second one is a FQL query

```
SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me()
```

Source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/

---

Shouldn't these two methods return the same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that the access token returned by the Graph API documentation includes the user_events permission, but the access token used by the FQL documentation does not?
Try running the second query with the access token used in the first